# Using a tuple (i,j,k,...) to construct an intersection list_of_sets[i] & list_of_sets[j] & list_of_sets[k]

Tags: python, set

I am searching through a tree. At each node, I need to find an intersection of some combination of sets, which are all contained in list_of_sets=[set_1,set_2,...,set_n].

I use a tuple of indexes to keep track of which node I am in, i.e. node=[i,j,k,...]. The size of this tuple varies from 1 to 5 depending on the position in the tree.

At any node, e.g. node=[i,j,k,l], I would like to construct such an expression:

```
intersection = list_of_sets[i] & list_of_sets[j] & list_of_sets[k] & list_of_sets[l]
```

I have absolutely no clue how get started on this one. Your advice is deeply appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [34]: sets, node = [{1, 4}, {4, 5}, {4, 10}], (0, 1, 2)

In [35]: set.intersection(*(sets[x] for x in node))
Out[35]: {4}
```

The above works because [sets' `intersection` method](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=intersection#set.intersection) accepts arbitrary number of sets for intersecting. You can also use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter):

```
In [38]: set.intersection(*itemgetter(*node)(sets))
Out[38]: {4}
```

Comment: It's cleaner to use `set.intersection` as an unbound method, so you can just write `set.intersection(*itemgetter(*node)(sets))`, without needing to distinguish as strictly between the set invoking the method and the other sets.